# Error while compiling Linux kernel 2.6: Length of array is not a constant

Tags: gcc, compilation, linux-kernel, makefile

I tried to compile Linux kernel v2.6 using the following command:

```
make CC="/home/ahmad/cilabp-master/CIL/bin/cilly" LD="/home/ahmad/cilabp-master/CIL/bin/cilly" -j4
```

But I received the following error:

```
include/linux/gfp.h:223: Error: Length of array is not a constant: 1 - 2 * ! (! ((59624 >> bit) & 1))
```

I commented the statement out and I received this kind of error from other places in the source. Therefore, I commented out all of the statements. But I received the following error:

```
...
gcc-4.6.real: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory
gcc-4.6.real: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory
gcc-4.6.real: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/acpi/realmode/wakeup.elf] Error 1
make[3]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/acpi/realmode/wakeup.bin] Error 2
make[2]: *** [arch/x86/kernel/acpi] Error 2
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/kernel] Error 2t
make: *** [arch/x86] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      fs/fs-writeback.o
...
```

And after that memory usage started to increase until I ran out of memory!